# Disable go vet checks for "composite literal uses unkeyed fields"

Tags: go, warnings, suppress-warnings

I'm running go vet on my CI tool, and started getting the error:

```
composite literal uses unkeyed fields
```

Because I'm instantiating

```
type A struct {
   *B
}
```

like this:

```
A{b} // b is of type *B
```

I don't care for this warning, and want to disable it on my go vet checks. How do I do this?

Comment: I think this is a bug in "go vet". There is no ambiguity in this case (only one member) and "go vet" should not report this as a problem. Same with multiple members that have incompatible types.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> ```
> $ go doc cmd/vet
> ```
>
> By default all checks are performed. If any flags are explicitly set
>   to true, only those tests are run. Conversely, if any flag is
>   explicitly set to false, only those tests are disabled. Thus
>   -printf=true runs the printf check, -printf=false runs all checks except the printf check.
>
> ```
> Unkeyed composite literals
>
> Flag: -composites
>
> Composite struct literals that do not use the field-keyed syntax.
> ```

Answer (score 44):

You can disable it or you can fix the code instead:

```
a := A{B: b}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/mW03O0Rl5I)

Comment: This is not a fix because there is no bug. This is a workaround for a bug in "go vet" that is overly religious on this matter.

Comment: As far as I know using unkeyed fields not only just fine, but very common practice for embedded types.

Comment: I don't understand what the warning is trying to prevent. Can someone explain? Why do you need a key there? My struct only has one parameter.

Comment: @KaMok mainly because say few weeks/months later you add a field to the struct, then everything that used the unkeyed initialization would break.

Comment: There _are_ times where unekeyed is a good idea. If you use keyed, and a few weeks/months later you add a field to the struct, you might want your initialisation code to break to see where you need to update your initialisation code.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49461373/) for why this is the right solution.

Answer (score 18):

If you're using the language server.

[`Gopls on by default in the VS Code Go extension`](https://blog.golang.org/gopls-vscode-go)

`gopls` *does* vet check by [default.](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/analyzers.md)

```
"gopls": {
     "analyses": { "composites": false }
 },
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using VS code, you have to manually set the flag under settings

`settings > Extensions > Go`

Scroll down to "Vet Flags" section

[image]

Add Item and add the flag

```
-composites=false .
```

Click ok.

Save one of your files again or restart VS code to see the effect.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable it with the `-composites=false` flag: e.g.,

```
go vet -composites=false .
```

NB: `go tool vet` is deprecated

Comment: Hi, does this work on VSCode as well? Or do I need to do something else?

Comment: @cruise_lab added a post as I had to go through few steps for VS Code

Answer (score 2):

```
go tool vet -composites=false .
```