# Go vet: "composite literal uses unkeyed fields" with embedded types

Tags: go, warnings

I have a simple structure:

```
type MyWriter struct {
    io.Writer
}
```

Which I then use in the following way:

```
writer = MyWriter{io.Stdout}
```

When running `go vet` this gives me a `composite literal uses unkeyed fields`.

In order to fix this would I have to turn io.Reader into a field in the `MyWriter` structure by adding a key?

```
type MyWriter struct {
    w io.Writer
}
```

Is there any other way around this? 
The only other answer I found on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273920/disable-go-vet-checks-for-composite-literal-uses-unkeyed-fields) suggests to disable the check altogether but I would rather not do that and find a proper solution.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```
writer = MyWriter{Writer: io.Stdout}
```

Embedded structs have an implicit key of the type name itself without the package prefix (e.g. in this case, `Writer`).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you also point me towards official doc that states it?

Comment: @mc9 https://go.dev/ref/spec#Struct_types "A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an embedded field.[...] The unqualified type name acts as the field name."